# How to get rid of noise in the water tap

Tags: water, faucet, noise, air, tap

When I turn my plumbing tap on , it gives some whistle sound and I always get the sound , every single time.

Please find AV clip [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1su_D3mdhRzSQZP-F5Iu642I8vrGTfs3B/view?usp=sharing).

None of the water taps give this whistle sound , how can I get rid of this noise.

Should I be worried ? Should I do something about it ?

Update:

The water comes from over head water tank in terrace

**Update 2:**

After cleaning the aerator , the sound stopped in the tap.

Please find below two AV clips: These below taps there's always a turbulent water flow .. I wonder some air bubble cause it . why ? this always happens , there are no aerators attached as well.

- [AV 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1II-0b2lMect2qkIud51Bn-v1mRdDGXx5/view)
- [AV 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U9mlz30PBO8ocjgXalj7eP-Solob0U-V/view)

Please find the below AV clip: All the taps except above two has streamlined water flow.Please see the video of streamlined water flow.

- [AV](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KXP4qO8WG3cn7743oIrtiXHpLo16iOen/view)

Comment: Please, share more details....

Comment: In my case, the problem was trapped air in the one section of the pipe I hadn't run to let the air out of: the dishwasher feed. Ran that briefly, whistle silenced. Make sure you have flushed _all_ the lines.

Comment: I tried running the water out but still the sound is coming

Comment: @gnicko - Could you please let me know what are the other details , that you are looking for ?

Comment: Does it do that chirp/whistle just once, or does it repeat? How often? What changes if you turn the tap on just a trickle or full on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the water flow, there's no bubbles in it, even though the faucet appears to have an aerator. If you remove the aerator, does the whistle stop? I suspect the aerator is clogged or defective. Abnormalities in water flow make odd noises.

Comment: Thanks , It was aerator which was causing the problem like you said , it's clogged

Comment: Could you check the updated qustion and leave the comments please

Comment: @King if you have a **new** question, ask a new question, don't edit the question that was correctly answered as asked. And mark the correct answer by selecting the check-mark on the answer that helped you the most. Take the [tour]

Comment: @Ecnerwal - You are right

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it could be mineral build up in the faucet or water pipes that's restricting the flow of water causing vibrations and the whistling noise first try changing or examining the filter that's in the faucets exit valve where the water comes out at and see what kind of build up is there if any.

Comment: Dirt got built up in the aerator so that's why the sound. I've updated my question .. could you please check and let me know your opinion